# Implement an AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection

I'm trying to use hibernate multi-tenancy (from [chapter 16](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)).

Right now my *ExtendedStorageManager* uses this method to start a multi-tenant session:

```
public Session getClabSession(int serverId, String customerSchema) {
    if (!clabFactories.containsKey(serverId)) {
        DbServers d = databaseConfigurations.get(serverId);
        clabCustomerConfig.setProperty(
            "hibernate.connection.url",
            ResourceBundleService.getInstance().decorateBundle(
                "database.connection.pattern", d.getHost(),
                d.getPort()));
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(clabCustomerConfig.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory factory = clabCustomerConfig
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        clabFactories.put(d.getId(), factory);
        serviceRegistry = null;
        factory = null;
    }
    Session session = clabFactories.get(serverId).withOptions()
        .tenantIdentifier(customerSchema).openSession();
    session.setDefaultReadOnly(false);
    return session;

}
```

Obviously I had a first error when testing because I totally missed the implementation of a *MultiTenantConnectionProvider* as explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4661).

Using grepcode I found out about [AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.CR1/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider.java) that looks like what I want to use. So I created my class extending it:

```
public class XMLDMultiTenantConnectionProvider extends
    AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6679645015449636823L;

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(
        String tenantIdentifier) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }

}
```

But I'm a bit clueless now on what to use to get a ConnectionProvider in these two cases. Can you help me?

PS: I found [ConnectionProviderBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-testing/4.0.0.Alpha2/org/hibernate/testing/env/ConnectionProviderBuilder.java#ConnectionProviderBuilder.buildConnectionProvider%28java.util.Properties,boolean%29). Do you think I can use it as an example to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can have your own implementation of the abstract class with something like the following :

```
public class XMLDMultiTenantConnectionProvider extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {


      private final ConnectionProvider xml1 = ConnectionProviderBuilder.buildConnectionProvider("xml1DataSource");
      private final ConnectionProvider xml2 = ConnectionProviderBuilder.buildConnectionProvider("xml2DataSource");

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6679645015449636823L;

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
         //Default Datasource (in this case i chose the first one as default)
         return xml1;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) {

    if( "xml1".equals(tenantIdentifier) ) 
        return xml1;

    if( "xml2".equals(tenantIdentifier) ) 
        return xml2;

    return null;
    }

}
```

I think that could be a good and understandable example ...

Comment: Two questions: 1) ConnectionBuilderProvider is a class from the testing package of hibernate. Should I use it in production? 2) Since I have 1000 schemas would it be correct to use like a map where I save all those connection providers and I pass one of them at the creation of the session? Could two different session use the same connection provider?

Comment: 1) You can use the connectionBuilderProvider class or you can construct instances directly from the constructor of the ConnectionProvider class.   2) Yes, using a map would be of course the best bet in that context .