# Using Tomcat in Production for Spring Boot apps

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, microservices

As a novice with Spring Boot , I need to know the following as I could not find google results in a straight forward manner. 
What application servers do they really use for deploying those Spring Boot applications in real life? 
Is Tomcat really used by companies - if so do they achieve it using clustering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring boot has an inbuilt Tomcat server, it's simply run from Java.

The Tomcat is built into the jar, so it's the same in any environment.

Here is a typical spring boot jar, with the tomcat jars shown:

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/boot-docker/target$ jar tvf boot-docker-1.0.3.jar | grep tomcat
  2293 Mon Jan 30 19:45:14 GMT 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
241640 Tue Jan 10 21:03:52 GMT 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar
3015953 Tue Jan 10 21:03:50 GMT 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar
239791 Tue Jan 10 21:03:50 GMT 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar
```

We run our spring boot applications as docker images (complete virtual Unix server) on Redhat Openshift cloud, which is typical.

BTW Tomcat is used commercially and is very reliable.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance - I have 2 queries that tag along 
1) So the real prod system will be fine with JUST being a *nix server with java installed?
2) So in that case do you just run 100s of instances of your Spring boot projects to handle a service ?

Comment: @Velan yes to point 1, usually they are run in a cloud which will elastically scale, but it would have to be a massive load to require 100s.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful explanations @EssexBoy

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot application, you can generate an application jar which **contains Embedded Tomcat**. You can run a web application as a normal Java application.

If you still want to deploy your application with Tomcat Server.

First, you need to package a **WAR application instead of a JAR**. For this, you need to change pom.xml with the following content:

```
<profiles>    
         <profile>
            <id>war</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Let’s modify the final WAR file name in **finalName** element. (for my case, output is ROOT.war)

Next, to initialize the Servlet context required by Tomcat by implementing the **SpringBootServletInitializer** interface:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Then, execute Maven command package with war profile:

```
mvn clean package -Pwar
```